# Chart goes out of the box when resizing screen

Tags: react-chartjs-2

enter code here[image]I am using react-chartjs-2 to implement chart modules. it is not responsive when we reisize screen

I am using Line component from react-chart-js-2

```
<Line options={options} data={data} height={80} />
```

Comment: we cannot just see your result without knowing the contents of your programs.

Comment: can you provide the html rendered result? for some case, you may need to manually change by using your own css.

Comment: did you have try this solutions? https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/531

Answer (score 0):

you should provide more details such as the component you used, parent divs, things like that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding position relative to the parent div works for me.